# Predetermined amount of characters into an array

Tags: php

I have a system that receives text like

> 99912345678910119999999999991234567891011999999999999123456789101199999999999912345678910119999999999991234567891011999999999999123456789101199999999999912345678910119999999999991234567891011999999999

As you can see it is a set of 25 characters being repeated.  I'm trying to take this jumble of information and assign each set of 25 characters to an array.

Do you think using substr and auto incrementing the amounts would work?

ie:

```
$numbers = "that number batch"; 
$i = 0;
$n = 25;
while (blabla) {
  $i + 25;
  $n + 25;
  $newnumber = subst($numbers, $i, $n);
}
```

I hope this made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split) ?

```
$numbers = str_split($numbers, 25);
```

Comment: This will do perfectly!  Thank you!